# How can I ignore this .build folder for ctags?

Tags: zsh, ctags, exuberant-ctags

I have Exuberant Ctags 5.8 and i'm trying to ignore the .build directory in: `packages/ANY/.build`. I'm also using ZSH via the oh-my-zsh addon.

I've tried using `--exclude=packages/*/.build/`, but I just get a
`zsh: no matches found: --exclude=packages/*/.build/`

The full command i'm using is:
`ctags -R  --exclude=node_modules --exclude=.meteor --exclude=packages/*/.build/`

If I ls the same pattern with `ls packages/*/.build/` then I get a list of each .build directory contents.

Is this a limitation of ctags?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to quote the `*` else it is interpreted by the shell. Here `zsh` tries to find files matching `--exclude=packages/*/.build`, which of course do not exist.

So this should do the trick:

```
ctags -R --exclude=node_modules --exclude=.meteor --exclude='packages/*/.build/'
```

Also, from `ctags(1)`

> **--exclude**=[pattern]
>   [...] (be sure to quote the option parameter to protect the wildcards from being expanded by the shell before being passed to ctags; also be aware that wildcards can match the slash character, '/') [...]